# How to send send push notification to multiple device using kreait/firebase cloud message in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a push notification to specific device (more than 1 device)

I've tried

```
$device = array('device1','device2');
```

> but error Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage::withTarget() must be
>   of the type string, array given

Also has tried

```
$device = 'device1,device2';
```

Also got an error. On the api document, it doesn't mention about format to send to multiple device.

Anyone can help?

Comment: The kreait Firebase SDK uses Firebases HTTP V1 API, which doesn‘t (yet?) support sending a message to multiple devices like this. You should create a topic, subscribe the devices to that topic and send the message to the topic.

Comment: @jeromegamez how to subscribe to topic for 1 device? shall be the device token in array?

Comment: See https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cloud-messaging.html#topic-management

Comment: There's now a Laravel Package for the SDK at https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase

Answer (score -1):

Need to send JSON array , just json_encode this array.

Comment: This is incorrect. (maintainer of the PHP SDK here )